# Unable to run WCAT against DotNetNuke with NTLM authentication

Tags: asp.net, iis, dotnetnuke, stress-testing, wcat

I have a ubr file setup to stress test an internal DotNetNuke site with WCAT:

```
transaction
{
    id = "Intranet Home Page";
    weight = 1000;

    cookies{clear = true;}
    sleep{delay = rand("1","500");}

    request
    {
        url         = "/";
        statuscode = 401;
    }

    request
    {
        url         = "/";
        authentication = ntlm;
        username = "mydomain\\accountname";
        password = "password";
        statuscode = 200;
    }

    close{ method = reset;}
}
```

When running this (wcat.wsf -run -clients localhost -s myserver -t test.ubr -f settings.ubr -x) I simply get lots of error 500s:

`2010-03-08 10:29:31 192.168.11.239 GET / - 80 - 192.168.52.139 - 401 2 2148074254`
`2010-03-08 10:29:31 192.168.11.239 GET / - 80 - 192.168.52.139 - 401 1 0`
`2010-03-08 10:29:31 192.168.11.239 GET /Default.aspx - 80 mydomain\myaccount  192.168.52.139 - 500 0 0`

DNN is reporting these errors as:

**AssemblyVersion:** 5.2.3
**PortalID:** 0
**PortalName:** My Company
**UserID:** -1
**UserName:**
**ActiveTabID:** 39
**ActiveTabName:** Home
**RawURL:** /Default.aspx
**AbsoluteURL:** /Default.aspx
**AbsoluteURLReferrer:**
**UserAgent:**
**DefaultDataProvider:** DotNetNuke.Data.SqlDataProvider, DotNetNuke.SqlDataProvider
**ExceptionGUID:** 28d8821f-1ef2-41db-8a65-d33e97a69130
**InnerException:**
**Unhandled Error:**
**FileName:**
**FileLineNumber:** 0
**FileColumnNumber:** 0
**Method:**  DotNetNuke.Authentication.ActiveDirectory.HttpModules.AuthenticationModule.OnAuthenticateRequest
**StackTrace:**
Message:  System.Exception:  Unhandled Error:
---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at  DotNetNuke.Authentication.ActiveDirectory.HttpModules.AuthenticationModule.OnAuthenticateRequest(Object s, EventArgs e) at  System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() at
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
**Source:**
**Server Name:** MYSERVER

It seems to be losing the username somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due to the DNN Windows Authentication module I was using. It looks like it redirects to an authentication page, sets a cookie, and then redirects back. WCAT couldn't cope with this for some reason. I ended up using WAST.